# Is it possible to automate the changing of an svn repository layout?

Tags: version-control, svn

I have an SVN repository which was moved from CVS a while back. It has a single `branches/tags/trunk` structure. Over time the main project was split to multiple library projects. The structure now looks something like this:

```
trunk\projects\prj1
trunk\projects\prj2
trunk\tools\tool1
trunk\tools\tool2
branches\b1\projects\prj1 
...
```

Is there an easy way (through a script perhaps) to convert this repository into a structure similar to:

```
projects\prj1\trunk
projects\prj1\branches\b1
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a script, unless you're going to have to repeat the process multiple times. Just use `svn move` and `svn rename` as appropriate to rearrange the structure. You can do it with repository URLs, or check out as little of the repository as possible using [sparse directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html), move everything around, then commit.

```
svn mkdir /projects/prj1 --parents
svn mkdir /projects/prj1/branches --parents
svn move trunk/projects/prj1 /projects/prj1/trunk
svn move branches/b1/projects/prj1 /projects/prj1/branches/b1
```

And so on. The reason I say you don't need to script it is because you're going to have so many different names & conditions to work through that it won't be worth the trouble.

Comment: With unified trunk, when the branch was created, it copied all projects. However likely only a few was modified. Is there any way to check if a project was modified in the branch? If it was not modified then I may not want to move it to the branch. Even, I may want to branch it only from the point it was modified in the unified branch.

Comment: Use `svn log --stop-on-copy <BRANCHURL>` to look for changes to the branch.